# Percentage of votes received in an election

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

> In an election, $70\%$ of males were registered voters and $40\%$ females were
>   registered voters, all registered males casted their votes. But only $65\%$ registered females casted their votes.
>   If there were only $2$ candidates in the election and they have received
>   the votes in the ratio $9:8$, how much percent (both men and women) of the registered voters casted their votes to the winner?

I have tried, but could not solve as number of males and females are not known. Is there any way to solve this. please help

Comment: See http://www.careerbless.com/qna/discuss.php?questionid=2907

Comment: You're probably expected to assume that there are equally many males and females in the population _in total_.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. without that this cannot be solved. thanks for the link also